# httpBasicBinding with authentication and no message or transport security

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got a small WCF service in intranet and I need to implement authentication in it. This service communicates with different Java clients over http (uses basicHttpBinding). I've tried to configure binding like so

```
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

And added service behaviour

```
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="LocalTasks.Services.Validators.IntegrationUserNameValidator,LocalTasks.Services"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
```

But calls to this service do not hit my custom UserNamePassword validator. 
I've also tried the same variant but with security mode set to Message and added a certificate. In this case validator worked fine.

How to configure service to authenticate users via basicHttpBinding without any message or transport security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. You need either message or transport security, in order to have the credentials encrypted when they travel from the client to the server.

You really should use Message or Transport security.

You could also use `TransportCredentialOnly`, which will not require an SSL certificate, but that is recommended for testing only.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Authentication" >
    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Cause it requires modification in legacy code of Java Clients. So there is no way to send credentials to server without any security over open http channel?

Comment: If you are stuck with no encryption anyway, then you could use security mode as 'TransportCredentialOnly'. See my edit.

Comment: I see. Any additional configuration of <transport clientCredentialType="???" />  needed?

Comment: clientCredentialType = "Basic" works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/> this variant is  not woking. Calls are been processed without any authentication.